# How can I add authenication fields to Firebase Trigger Email? I keep getting the error: "Missing credentials for PLAIN"

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-extensions

I am working on an email notification project for a school district.  I am using the Flutter platform and have connected to Firebase.  I have added the Trigger Email extension, set up the collection in Firestore and set up a Sendgrid account for the SMTP server.  I created a test email directly in the Firestore collection with the configured collection name for the Trigger Email service.  My collection document in firestore looks like this:

```
message:
subject: Hello from Firebase!
text: This is the plain text body.
html: This is the <code>HTML</code> body
to: xxxxx@gmail.com // my receiving email address
```

The extension attempts to send the email but then adds this to the document a few seconds later:

```
delivery
attempts: 1
endTime: //a time in UTC
error: "Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN""
leaseExpireTime: null
startTime: //a time in UTC
state: "ERROR"
```

Comment: Do you use the latest version? If your SMTP password contains special characters, it might fail with earlier versions. Check [this issue](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/issues/996), maybe your problem is related.

Comment: No dice.  Tried the rollback version and the updated version base on the comments on the Github post.

Comment: Have you completed authentication under `Settings/Sender Authentication` in SendGrid? Have you set `SMTP connection URI` and other parameters in Trigger Email extension, under `Extension configuration`? Also, you have to provider grant the extension's service account, under `Access and roles`.

Comment: Yes, it appears all of these aspects have been set up.  My SMTP connection URI is the one given on the Sendgrid set-up guide.  I added the password as the api key string.  Access and roles was set up through the Firebase wizard.

Comment: Success!  I reset the API key in sendgrid, then made sure to use a real email address and not an alias.  Thanks @peter-koltai!

Answer (score 0):

A safety way to do it could be editing the Function itself directly in the Firebase console. Follows the steps to do so:

**1)** In the Firebase Console on the left menu select **Functions**.

[image]

**2)** In the list of the functions select the function check the **ext-firestore-send-email-processQueue** function, and click on the three dots ==> **detailed usage statistics**

[image]

**3)** After this, on the new opened tab click the button to edit function.
[image]
And now find the **Execution environment, build, connections and security settings**

**4)** Create a environment variable named **SMTP_PASSWORD** and add the password to the **Value** field.

[image]

**5)** On the bottom bar click on the **Next** button then click **Deploy**.

This solves the lack of authentication and makes the password available through the environment variable.